# how to using doctrine query builder in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I have a problem:
I am using doctrine 2 and codeigniter 2. I want to know how does doctrine query builder work? I want to use `select` query on doctrine query builder, but I can't do it. I've also read doctrine documents and tried, but I was not successful.

After trying this, I get this error message :

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT u.username, u.password, u.email FROM Entity\Userss u, Userss u ORDER BY u.username ASC' in C:\xampp\htdocs\hotell\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php:39 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotell\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php(429): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT u.userna...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotell\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php(854): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('Class 'Userss' ...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotell\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php(1529): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->AbstractSchemaName() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotell\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php(1426): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->RangeVariableDeclaration() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotell\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php(1173): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->IdentificationVariableDeclaration() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotell\applic in **C:\xampp\htdocs\hotell\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php on line 49**

My entity code:

```
<?php    
namespace Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user")
 */
class Userss
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=32, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    public $username;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    public $password;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     * The @JoinColumn is not necessary in this example. When you do not specify
     * a @JoinColumn annotation, Doctrine will intelligently determine the join
     * column based on the entity class name and primary key.
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group")
     * @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    public function setUsername($Username)
    {
      $this->username = $Username;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
      return $this->username;
    }

    // and more...
}
```

and this is my code in model that extends from CI_Model:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
require_once APPPATH . 'modules/user/models/entity/user_modell.php';


  class User_model extends CI_Model
  {
    public $em;
    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();

      $this->em = $this->doctrine->em;
    }


    function test()
    {
      $repo = $this->em->getRepository('Entity\\Userss', 'u');
      $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('u')
                 ->select('u.username, u.password, u.email')
                 ->from('Userss', 'u')
                 ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC')
                 ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
      var_dump($qb);
      die;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you seen this : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html ?

Comment: yes, I read and applied this document, but I got the same error :(

Comment: that works! I comment this : namespace Entity; but I don't its reason...

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

into

```
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

it worked for me.